# R lattice bar chart: specify colour of legend?

Tags: r, lattice

My data looks like this:

```
service,rating_1,rating_2,rating_3,rating_4,rating_5
renew_patent,0,0,1,2,11
apply_benefit,21,20,121,828,1744
apply_employment_tribunal,0,0,0,0,0
```

I want R to print me a histogram for each row, with the columns as the bars of the histogram.

I've got this so far:

```
require(lattice)
data <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE)
colors = c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green')
barchart(rating_1+rating_2+rating_3+rating_4+rating_5 ~ service, data=data, 
  auto.key=list(space='right'), scales=list(x=list(rot=45)), 
  ylab="Percentage of total", col=colors)
```

It's working, but it's only changing the colour of the bars, not the colour of the legend.

How can I specify the colour of the legend as well as the bars?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rather than passing a `col=` parameter to `barchart`, lattice much prefers if you change the `par.settings`. In this case. the color of the bars is determined by superpose.polygon because you have different groups of ratings. This should do what you want

```
data<-data.frame(
    service = c("renew_patent", "apply_benefit", "apply_employment_tribunal"),
    rating_1 = c(0, 21, 0), 
    rating_2 = c(0, 20, 0),
    rating_3 = c(1, 121, 0), 
    rating_4 = c(2, 828, 0),
    rating_5 = c(11, 1744, 0)
)

colors = c('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blue', 'green')
barchart(rating_1+rating_2+rating_3+rating_4+rating_5 ~ service, data=data, 
  auto.key=list(space='right'), scales=list(x=list(rot=45)), 
  ylab="Percentage of total", par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=colors)))
```